# Why do I get "Internal Server Error" when I try to return an object from a Dancer2 route with the JSON serializer?

Tags: perl, dancer

I have a Dancer2 application that I want to return a serialized version of an object using the JSON serializer.  Here's a small version of it:

```
{
  package User;

  use Moo;
  use Types::Standard qw/Str/;
  has name => (is=>'ro',isa =>Str, default => "");

  sub TO_JSON { return { %{ shift() } };}
}

use Dancer2;
set serializer => 'JSON';
set engines=>{serializer=>{JSON=>{allow_blessed=>1,convert_blessed=>1}}};

get '/hello/:name' => sub {
  my $user = User->new({name=>route_parameters->{name}});
  return $user->TO_JSON;  ## error if the TO_JSON method is not explicitly called. 
};
dance;
1;
```

If the `TO_JSON` method is explicitly called, then obviously the object is returned as a hash ref and then serialized as:

```
{"name":"fred"}
```

as an example.  If the last line in the GET is

```
return $user;
```

then the following error is returned:

```
{"title":"Error 500 - Internal Server Error","message":"","status":500,"exception":"Unrecognized response type from route: User.\n"}
```

I thought that setting the `allow_blessed` and `convert_blessed` would handle calling `TO_JSON` automatically, however I can't find the documentation on this for Dancer2.  Is this something that was dropped?

Answer (score 0):

Dancer2 doesn't support returning arbitrary objects from route handlers. You can only return objects of the [following types](https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/Dancer2-0.204004/lib/Dancer2/Core/Route.pm#L135):

- Plack::Response
- Dancer2::Core::Response
- Dancer2::Core::Response::Delayed

The type is checked before serialization, so the serializer is never even invoked if the object type is unsupported.

It looks like arbitrary objects were [supported at one point](http://lists.preshweb.co.uk/pipermail/dancer-users/2015-July/004671.html), but not any more. The workaround is to return a non-blessed reference, as you've already discovered.